# Don't require semicolon in singleline block

Tags: tslint

Eslint for [semicolons](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi) has option `omitLastInOneLineBlock`:

```
"semi": ["error", "always", { "omitLastInOneLineBlock": true }],
```

I'd like to use similar setting with tslint. How can I configure it?

Here is my `tslint.json`:

```
{
    "defaultSeverity": "error",
    "extends": [
        "tslint:latest",
        "tslint-react"
    ],
    "jsRules": {},
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-expression": [true, "allow-fast-null-checks"]
    },
    "rulesDirectory": []
}
```